# Is there a way to cache the .all call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

For example i have this in my index controller

```
@users = User.current
```

this is my User model

```
 scope :current, :conditions => { :active => true }, :order => 'LOWER(first_name), LOWER(last_name) ASC'
```

Which is basically grabbing all the records and I am not paginating because I am using the jquery datatables table that has a great filter search... the problem I am wanting to achieve is to cache these if possible unless there are new users...which doesnt happen very often

I read about fresh_when but didnt know what could be used here

**UPDATE**

After following the answer below i dont see CACHE in the log all i see is

```
  Company Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` INNER JOIN `positions` ON `companies`.`id` = `positions`.`company_id` WHERE `positions`.`user_id` = 551
  Company Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` INNER JOIN `positions` ON `companies`.`id` = `positions`.`company_id` WHERE `positions`.`user_id` = 93
  Company Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` INNER JOIN `positions` ON `companies`.`id` = `positions`.`company_id` WHERE `positions`.`user_id` = 668
```

Comment: How many users do you have in your DB?

Answer (score 6):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :clear_cache

  def self.current
    Rails.cache.fetch("current_users", expires_in: 1.hour) do
      User.where(active: true).order("LOWER(first_name), LOWER(last_name) ASC").all
    end
  end

private

  def clear_cache
    Rails.cache.delete("current_users")
  end

end
```

Ensure that caching is enabled in config/environments/*.rb:

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

This is what you want. Read more here:
http://robotmay.com/post/23161612605/everyone-should-be-using-low-level-caching?bda26d48
http://www.tmatthew.net/blog/rails-caching-example
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch

When storing models in the cache, you may run into an odd problem that occurs when the cache is fetched before the models are loaded. Not to worry, this will only happen in development, and there's a fix (application_controller.rb):

```
before_filter :load_models_if_dev
def load_models_if_dev
    if Rails.env == 'development'
        User; Post; Comment # whatever other classes that can get cached.
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**
Notice the `.all` in `User.where().order().all`. Without that, the value stored in the cache is just an ActiveRecord Relation and not the actual results. Without the .all a query will still have to run. Thanks @Frederick Cheung for bringing that to our attention.

Comment: Your solution seems great but when i look at the logs i dont see cache I see the plain sql everytime...i will update my question

Comment: oh yeah... caching is disabled by default in development... see edit

Comment: One reservation -- Rails is using `FileStore` by default with marshal/unmarshal which might be slower than direct SQL (depends on local disk), also it's enabled by default in R3.2

Comment: Strange because i changed config.action_controller.perform_caching to true and still not seeing cache in the development log....i restarted and still straight sql...I am using rails 3.2.6 if that matters

Comment: Another problem BTW, this time more serious, with multi-server config you are clearing local cache (unless you are using `FileStore` on a shared directory), what about other servers?

Comment: If you're going to use Rails.cache you need to be calling .all (or similar) on your scope or else you are only caching the scope object, not the result of its execution

Comment: you mean Rails.cache.all.fetch

Comment: can you elaborated what you mean by .all